# SML Types of rules don't agree and righthand side of clause doesn't agree with function result type

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm trying to write a function in sml that takes  a function and applies it to all elements in a list. If any element returns NONE then the entire function evals to NONE but if any element returns SOME v then that element is added to the accumulator.

The final return value is SOME of the acculumator. Right now I'm getting two errors.

1. hw4.sml:93.21-95.67 Error: types of rules don't agree [tycon mismatch]
   earlier rule(s): 'Z option -> 'Y option
   this rule: 'Z option -> 'X list
   in rule:
   SOME v => ((all_answers_helper ) xs') v @ acc
2. hw4.sml:90.5-95.67 Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [tycon mismatch]
   expression:  'Z list -> 'Y list -> 'Y list option
   result type:  'Z list -> 'Y list -> 'Y list
   in declaration:
   all_answers_helper = (fn arg => (fn  => ))

```
fun all_answers_helper f xs acc = 
        case xs of 
        [] => SOME acc
        | x::xs' => case f x of 
                    NONE => NONE
                    | SOME v => all_answers_helper f xs' v @ acc
```

But I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're getting tripped up by operator precedence. Prefix function and constructor application ("normal ones", like `SOME`) bind tighter than infix application. So when you write `all_answers_helper f xs' v @ acc` that's the same as `(all_answers_helper f xs' v) @ acc`---the application of `all_answers_helper` binds tighter than that of `@`.

You can fix this by doing `all_answers_helper f xs' (v @ acc)` instead. Note that this would imply that `v` is itself a list. Based on your description of adding "the element" to the accumulator it is possible you instead mean `all_answers_helper f xs' (v :: acc)`, i.e., to just cons the element on instead of appending two lists together.

Answer (score 0):

I think @kopecs has it, but you may also find it useful to make use of pattern matching right in the function signature to make your code easier to reason about.

```
fun all_answers_helper _ [] acc = SOME acc
  | all_answers_helper f (x::xs) acc = 
      case f x of 
          NONE => NONE
        | SOME v => all_answers_helper f xs (v :: acc)
```

Understanding operator precedence is crucial to avoid programming errors, but you can also sidestep this by introducing local bindings.

```
fun all_answers_helper _ [] acc = SOME acc
  | all_answers_helper f (x::xs) acc = 
      case f x of 
          NONE => NONE
        | SOME v => 
             let 
               val updated_acc = v :: acc
             in
               all_answers_helper f xs updated_acc
             end
```